# CartoDB can I turn off comments?

Tags: carto

With a free CartoDB account, visitors can leave comments on your map/data.  Is there any way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ramiroaznar says, there's no option for turning off the Disqus comments, but there's a trick/hack that can be used:

In your account settings, inside the Profile section, there's a "Disqus shortname" field. If you write there a Disqus shortname that does not exist, the Disqus comment block will fail to load, so nobody could leave comments there.

[image: disqus]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no option for turning off comments in your public profile. But if you can share your map in your website or blog as a embedded element the comments will not be displayed. A last option can be getting [a CartoDB plan](https://cartodb.com/pricing-features/) then you will be able to change the privacy settings of your datasets and maps.

Note: comments can be good feedback to improve your maps! ;-)

Comment: Many thanks.  My client was concerned about trolls but if most people don't see the comments it can't be too bad. Plan pricing is unaffordable for him.